# Has anyone gotten Oracle Lite to run on Windows Mobile 6.1 client

Tags: oracle, mobile

The title pretty much says it all.

I'm trying to run an Oracle Lite application using a Windows Mobile 6.1 device.  I keep getting "invalid database or password" errors.  (It's not the password...)

The device I'm using requires 6.1, so I haven't been able to try with 5.0 or 6.0.

Has anyone gotten this combination to work?  If so HOW?

I cannot even get the Transport demo running on the client.

Comment: Which version of Oracle Lite?

Comment: The version is 10.3.0.2.  I applied patches 8915800 and 8536828, as recommended on metalink but still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packaging wizard didn't set the Database Username and password properly.

I had to go into the mobile manager web page, select the application and set the Database Username and Password fields.

Once I did that, the synchronization worked like a charm.